# Few fragments with google map api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-viewpager

i need to make a FragmentPagerAdapter with Fragment who contains `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`

```
FragmentPagerAdapter:

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return TargetFragment.getInstance(tasks.getTaskList().get(position));
    }
```

TargetFragment layout:

```
...
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

but if i have more than one TargetFragment i get an error

```
IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #119: Duplicate id 0x7f080073, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

Comment: Should i remove fragment view after swipe it and create new one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [App crashes with FragmentManager Replace when using GoogleMaps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119051/app-crashes-with-fragmentmanager-replace-when-using-googlemaps)